# How to check if an IP address is reserved without using ipaddress module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), the following are all the reserved IPv4 addresses:

```
RESERVED_IPV4 = [
    '0.0.0.0/8',
    '10.0.0.0/8',
    '100.64.0.0/10',
    '127.0.0.0/8',
    '169.254.0.0/16',
    '172.16.0.0/12',
    '192.0.0.0/24',
    '192.0.2.0/24',
    '192.88.99.0/24',
    '192.168.0.0/16',
    '198.18.0.0/15',
    '198.51.100.0/24',
    '203.0.113.0/24',
    '224.0.0.0/4',
    '233.252.0.0/24',
    '240.0.0.0/4',
    '255.255.255.255/32'
]
```

I want to check if any given IP address is reserved without using `ipaddress`, this is trivial, I only need to check if it falls into any of the address ranges.

I have programmatically converted the reserved networks to start, end IP pairs of `int`s:

```
RESERVED_IPV4 = [
    (0, 16777215),
    (167772160, 184549375),
    (1681915904, 1686110207),
    (2130706432, 2147483647),
    (2851995648, 2852061183),
    (2886729728, 2887778303),
    (3221225472, 3221225727),
    (3221225984, 3221226239),
    (3227017984, 3227018239),
    (3232235520, 3232301055),
    (3323068416, 3323199487),
    (3325256704, 3325256959),
    (3405803776, 3405804031),
    (3758096384, 4294967295)
]
```

A naïve solution would be to check if a number falls into any of the ranges, like so:

```
RESERVED_IPV4_RANGES = [range(*e) for e in RESERVED_IPV4]

def is_reserved_range(ip):
    return any(ip in e for e in RESERVED_IPV4_RANGES)
```

But this is inefficient. Since these are IP addresses, all IP addresses in the same range share the same binary prefix:

```
In [252]: [(f'{a:032b}', f'{b:032b}') for a, b in RESERVED_IPV4]
Out[252]:
[('00000000000000000000000000000000', '00000000111111111111111111111111'),
 ('00001010000000000000000000000000', '00001010111111111111111111111111'),
 ('01100100010000000000000000000000', '01100100011111111111111111111111'),
 ('01111111000000000000000000000000', '01111111111111111111111111111111'),
 ('10101001111111100000000000000000', '10101001111111101111111111111111'),
 ('10101100000100000000000000000000', '10101100000111111111111111111111'),
 ('11000000000000000000000000000000', '11000000000000000000000011111111'),
 ('11000000000000000000001000000000', '11000000000000000000001011111111'),
 ('11000000010110000110001100000000', '11000000010110000110001111111111'),
 ('11000000101010000000000000000000', '11000000101010001111111111111111'),
 ('11000110000100100000000000000000', '11000110000100111111111111111111'),
 ('11000110001100110110010000000000', '11000110001100110110010011111111'),
 ('11001011000000000111000100000000', '11001011000000000111000111111111'),
 ('11100000000000000000000000000000', '11111111111111111111111111111111')]
```

So a smarter approach would be checking if the binary representation of an IP address starts with any of the prefixes:

```
def longest_common_prefix(a, b):
    short = min(len(a), len(b))
    for i in range(short):
        if a[:i] != b[:i]:
            break
    return a[:i-1] if i else ''

RESERVED_IPV4_PREFIXES = tuple(longest_common_prefix(f'{a:032b}', f'{b:032b}') for a, b in RESERVED_IPV4)

def is_reserved_prefix(ip):
    return f'{ip:032b}'.startswith(RESERVED_IPV4_PREFIXES)
```

The prefixes are:

```
In [253]: RESERVED_IPV4_PREFIXES
Out[253]:
('00000000',
 '00001010',
 '0110010001',
 '01111111',
 '1010100111111110',
 '101011000001',
 '110000000000000000000000',
 '110000000000000000000010',
 '110000000101100001100011',
 '1100000010101000',
 '110001100001001',
 '110001100011001101100100',
 '110010110000000001110001',
 '111')
```

I have confirmed the second method is more efficient than the first:

```
In [254]: import random

In [255]: n = random.randrange(2**32)

In [256]: n
Out[256]: 634831452

In [257]: is_reserved_prefix(n)
Out[257]: False

In [258]: is_reserved_range(n)
Out[258]: False

In [259]: %timeit is_reserved_range(n)
1.92 µs ± 56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [260]: %timeit is_reserved_prefix(n)
734 ns ± 6.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

But can it get any more efficient? Like directly using bitwise operations on `int`s? I know how to convert to and from IP addresses using bitwise operations, but I don't know how to use them in this case.

---

I have confirmed directly comparing `int`s is slower than the smart approach as well:

```
In [261]: %timeit any(a <= n <= b for a, b in RESERVED_IPV4)
1.71 µs ± 6.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

---

I have finally managed to do it using bitwise and, however I don't know why this is actually slower than the `str.startswith` based approach. And what baffles me most is that `any` is actually slower than a `for` loop with early return:

```
RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS = []

for a, b in RESERVED_IPV4:
    count = b - a + 1
    x = count.bit_length() - 1
    y = 32 - x
    mask = ((1<<y)-1)<<x
    RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS.append((a, mask))

RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS = tuple(RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS)

def is_reserved_mask(ip):
    return any(ip & mask == start for start, mask in RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS)
```

```
In [332]: RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS = []
     ...:
     ...: for a, b in RESERVED_IPV4:
     ...:     count = b - a + 1
     ...:     x = count.bit_length() - 1
     ...:     y = 32 - x
     ...:     mask = ((1<<y)-1)<<x
     ...:     RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS.append((a, mask))
     ...:
     ...: RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS = tuple(RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS)

In [333]: def is_reserved_mask(ip):
     ...:     return any(ip & mask == start for start, mask in RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS)

In [334]: %timeit is_reserved_mask(n)
2.12 µs ± 53.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [335]: def is_reserved_mask(ip):
     ...:     for start, mask in RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS:
     ...:         if ip & mask == start:
     ...:             return True
     ...:     return False

In [336]: %timeit is_reserved_mask(n)
1.3 µs ± 97.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

I don't know why my code isn't as efficient as I imagined.

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient? Testing if a number is in a range is easy.

Comment: Remember that the `/<number>` part of the CIDR block is the number of leading bits to compare. So you basically need to convert both the network address and the IP address to 32-bit binary, extract the first `<number>` bits, and compare them.

Comment: So is your question how you can avoid using `tuple()`, `any()`, `range()`, `min()`, or other built-in functions (as per the question title), or how you can make your code more efficient, or why one version of the code is not as efficient as you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a binary search would be somewhat faster.  Also, since most IPs will not be reserved, you could optimize this further with a set of the first bytes that are in the reserved ranges (i.e. don't even do the binary search when the first byte of ip is not in that set).

```
RESERVED_IPV4 = [
    '0.0.0.0/8',
    '10.0.0.0/8',
    '100.64.0.0/10',
    '127.0.0.0/8',
    '169.254.0.0/16',
    '172.16.0.0/12',
    '192.0.0.0/24',
    '192.0.2.0/24',
    '192.88.99.0/24',
    '192.168.0.0/16',
    '198.18.0.0/15',
    '198.51.100.0/24',
    '203.0.113.0/24',
    '224.0.0.0/4',
    '233.252.0.0/24',
    '240.0.0.0/4',
    '255.255.255.255/32'
]

def ip2int(ip):
    return sum(int(p)<<i for i,p in zip([24,16,8,0],ip.split('.')))

ipRanges = [(ip2int(ip),ip2int(ip)+(1<<32>>int(m))-1) 
            for rip in RESERVED_IPV4 for ip,m in [rip.split("/")]]

ipStarts,ipEnds = zip(*sorted(ipRanges))
firstByte = { b for s,e in ipRanges for b in range(s>>24,(e>>24)+1) }

from bisect import bisect_right
def isReserved(ip):
    if ip>>24 not in firstByte: return False
    i = max(0,bisect_right(ipStarts,ip)-1)
    return ipStarts[i] <= ip <= ipEnds[i]
```

output:

```
>>> isReserved(ip2int('10.0.1.23'))
True
>>> isReserved(ip2int('11.0.0.0'))
False
```

performance:

```
from timeit import timeit

ip = 1842720477 # False
t  = timeit(lambda: isReserved(ip), number=1000000) 
print(t) # 0.21 microsecond per call 

ip = 167772439 # True
t = timeit(lambda: isReserved(ip), number=1000000)
print(t) # 0.60 microsecond per call
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in the past. Actually two different something similars:

1. With IP addresses, I've worked on an IPAM where I needed to hand-roll an efficient check if one address or prefix was inside another prefix.

   Based on that, I would agree with your intuition that in principle, a bitwise comparison should be fastest - *if* we can do those bitwise operations without too many Python interpreter overheads. In CPython in particular, you pay a substantial cost for every bytecode, while something like `string.startswith` is probably implemented entirely in C.
2. I also had to manually implement an efficient test which would make a lot of sense for multi-prefix `string.starswith`, as part of [how my `macaddress` library parses formats](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/python-macaddress/blob/2a90325f935dae71a3544c00a9950ddb048fac57/macaddress.py#L359-L389).

   I mention this because if I had to guess, `string.startswith` just does a simplified version of what I did there: check the next character of each candidate, and throw out the candidates that don't match - if there are enough candidates to make it worth it, we can first sort the candidates and then do a binary search for each character in the input to narrow down the start and end of the candidates that match so far.

Now, as for this:

> what baffles me most is that `any` is actually slower than a `for` loop with early return

It's because your `any` is wrapping a Python loop (a generator expression is just a Python loop wrapped up in an implicit generator function, basically):

```py
any(ip & mask == start for start, mask in RESERVED_IPV4_MASKS)
```

All that stuff inside the `any(...)` is paying the same overheads as your loop does, the `any` is just optimizing out the `if` and the `break` for you (you're also taking on the overheads inherent in Python's generator implementation, but those are probably relatively minor in comparison too).

You can try improving the performance by replacing the generator expression with a `map` after pulling the test+unpack into a function.

---

Also, a bigger-picture note: if you need to optimize Python performance, unless you're absolutely stuck with CPython and interpreted Python source, you should start by looking at PyPy or Cython - it is often a big waste of effort to hand-twiddle Python source, because you can get bigger gains by just compiling the relevant Python pieces to C or using a JiT-optimized Python.

Answer (score -1):

if the address anded with the network mask is equal to start address then the address is reserved.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

RESERVED_IPV4 = [
    '0.0.0.0/8',
    '10.0.0.0/8',
    '100.64.0.0/10',
    '127.0.0.0/8',
    '169.254.0.0/16',
    '172.16.0.0/12',
    '192.0.0.0/24',
    '192.0.2.0/24',
    '192.88.99.0/24',
    '192.168.0.0/16',
    '198.18.0.0/15',
    '198.51.100.0/24',
    '203.0.113.0/24',
    '224.0.0.0/4',
    '233.252.0.0/24',
    '240.0.0.0/4',
    '255.255.255.255/32'
]
def ip_bin( ip:str)->int: # convert address to integer
  parts = ip.split('.')
  b = int( parts[0])
  for i in [1,2,3]:
    b = (b << 8) + int( parts[i])
  return b

unknown = ip_bin( sys.argv[1])
rsvd = True  
for ip_a in RESERVED_IPV4:
  start_a,width_a = ip_a.split( '/') # split in 2 fields
  start = ip_bin( start_a)
  width = int( width_a)
  mask = ((1 << width) -1) << (32-width) # build network mask
  if (unknown & mask) == start: break
else:
  rsvd = False

print( "rsvd is", rsvd)
```